# GMP convert mpz to mpf

Tags: c, gmp

I am using GMP, and I want to be able to quickly convert an `mpz` to an `mpf`. I looked through the library and couldn't find much. The best thing I could think of was this:

```
mpz_t x;
/* Insert code here that assigns some value to x */
char buf[SIZE];
gmp_sprintf(buf, "%Zd", x);
mpf_t y;
mpf_set_str(y, buf);
```

This solution requires repeated conversion to and from a string. Also, it is limited by `SIZE`, and I see no way to predetermine how large `SIZE` needs to be. Is there any better way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about using `mpf_set_z (mpf_t rop, mpz_t op)` ?

Also (I assume you've done this) your mpz and mpf variables will need initialising with `mpf_init(mpf_t x)` and `mpz_init(mpz_t x)`.

So you'd do:

```
mpz_t x;
mpz_init(x);
/* Insert code here that assigns some value to x */
mpf_t y;
mpf_init(y);
mpf_set_z(y,x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow, given the bad reputation of `sprintf` I'm surprised they even included a function like it.

[`mpz_sizeinbase`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Miscellaneous-Integer-Functions.html) can be used to figure out how much space you will need to hold a base 10 representation of an integer.  And the other person who answered is correct, [`mpf_set_z`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Floats.html) is a much better way than converting the integer to a base 10 string and reading it back into a float.